# Make the main page full screen without scrolling

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox

Vue app. Please tell me how to make the start page full screen. So that there are no scroll bars in the main window, at any scale.
The scrollbar should be on "div class="bottom-center"".

```
<script setup>
import Comp from './Comp.vue';
</script>
<template>
  <div class="root">
    <div style="font-size:30px">menu</div>
    <Comp></Comp>
  </div>
</template>
<style>
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
.root  {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
</style>
```

Comp.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="top-left" style="background:red">top-left</div>
    <div class="top-center" style="background:blue">top-center</div>
    <div class="top-right" style="background:green">top-right</div>
    <div class="bottom-left" style="background:yellow">bottom-left</div>
    <div class="bottom-center" style="background:white;overflow-y:scroll">
      <div v-for="item in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]" :key="item" style="height:150px">{{item}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-right" style="background:grey">bottom-right</div>
  </div>
</template>
<style>
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5rem 18rem 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 4rem 1fr;
  grid-area: 'top-left top-center top-right' 'bottom-left "bottom-center bottom-right';
}
</style>
```

[Vue playground...](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the scrollbar on 'bottom-center' just remove the 'overflow-y: scroll'

```
<div class="bottom-center" style="background:white;"></div>
```

If you want to span the div class container to fill the whole page in height, you can set the height fot the div to 100vh (or a different value, depending on the other elements on the page). If you do so make sure u also remove the fixed height on the div-element inside the bottom-center div.

```
<div v-for="item in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]" :key="item">{{item}}</div>
```

Viewport-percentage Lengths: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

Comment: I probably wrote it unclearly because I am using a translator. 
It is required that there is no scrolling on the start page, but there should be scrolling in the 'bottom-center', since there will be a long list there.